# Find (to recover or permanently delete) deleted versioned S3 file

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with versioning turned on. I want to figure out how to permanently delete a file and all its version (for security reasons) and be able to recover a deleted file.

I know I need to remove the Delete Marker from other posts, but I cannot find the necessary information from `s3api list-object-versions`

1) I performed a small test and **uploaded** a file via console called `smallerfile.txt`, then ran the list command

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket myBucket --prefix small
```

2) I was presented with all of its info such VersionId, ETag, Key, Size, etc...

3) I then confirmed via console the file was there and showed its version, and then **Deleted** the file via console.

4) I re-ran the same list-object-versions command expecting to see the file but instead I get **no results**.

**How can I find the deleted file** and its delete marker?

Maybe I'm just using the wrong find command or missing a param?

---

example console outputs to show exactly what I mean;

[ uploaded file via console ]

```
joshua$ aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket myBucket --prefix small
{
    "Versions": [
        {
            "LastModified": "2019-07-26T17:22:35.000Z",
            "VersionId": "miVHm_RA7Bedy4FEYXjLt537V677UT",
            "ETag": "\"0f343b0944326a20f133d67c2b984a3b\"",
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Key": "smallerfile.txt",
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "joshua",
                "ID": "5fcc1002f611303c07ed02d117bbac143ac3f032daf63d60340b7b13050b"
            },
            "IsLatest": true,
            "Size": 1024
        }
    ]
}
```

[ deleted file via console]

```
joshua$ aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket myBucket --prefix small
joshua$
```

[ no results displayed ]

Answer (score 0):

These are the list of commands by which I can delete a file and still see the versions with deleted markers. Can you check if this is working for you.

```
//Create two versions of file
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://test-bucket/
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://test-bucket/

//List versions
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket test-bucket --prefix test
{
    "Versions": [
        {
            "LastModified": "2019-07-26T22:53:59.000Z", 
            "VersionId": "0aZ4LMY7soSaVFQTpjjJUHZTT6lJCwzN", 
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"", 
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD", 
            "Key": "test.txt", 
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "vivek", 
                "ID": "dcee5bd529e98b42307b49afc9ec9c5508391cc46f27e9c81257cee2e817be2a"
            }, 
            "IsLatest": true, 
            "Size": 0
        }, 
        {
            "LastModified": "2019-07-26T22:53:53.000Z", 
            "VersionId": "lUfo.1i4.az3mkv4TjxMnW74EjiaISHk", 
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"", 
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD", 
            "Key": "test.txt", 
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "vivek", 
                "ID": "dcee5bd529e98b42307b49afc9ec9c5508391cc46f27e9c81257cee2e817be2a"
            }, 
            "IsLatest": false, 
            "Size": 0
        }
    ]
}
//Remove file. Works on console also
aws s3 rm s3://test-bucket/test.txt


//Deleted marker in the version
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket test-bucket --prefix test
{
    "DeleteMarkers": [
        {
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "vivek", 
                "ID": "dcee5bd529e98b42307b49afc9ec9c5508391cc46f27e9c81257cee2e817be2a"
            }, 
            "IsLatest": true, 
            "VersionId": "eg4AqA6Q_UrANEZpw.1_ek8S0ZxhNVJQ", 
            "Key": "test.txt", 
            "LastModified": "2019-07-26T22:54:59.000Z"
        }
    ], 
    "Versions": [
        {
            "LastModified": "2019-07-26T22:53:59.000Z", 
            "VersionId": "0aZ4LMY7soSaVFQTpjjJUHZTT6lJCwzN", 
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"", 
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD", 
            "Key": "test.txt", 
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "vivek", 
                "ID": "dcee5bd529e98b42307b49afc9ec9c5508391cc46f27e9c81257cee2e817be2a"
            }, 
            "IsLatest": false, 
            "Size": 0
        }, 
        {
            "LastModified": "2019-07-26T22:53:53.000Z", 
            "VersionId": "lUfo.1i4.az3mkv4TjxMnW74EjiaISHk", 
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"", 
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD", 
            "Key": "test.txt", 
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "vivek", 
                "ID": "dcee5bd529e98b42307b49afc9ec9c5508391cc46f27e9c81257cee2e817be2a"
            }, 
            "IsLatest": false, 
            "Size": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Interesting, yes this works this way it seems that deleting the file from the console delete all its versions. Apparently this is also happening when files are deleted via the javascript sdk even though the docs explicitly state the opposite. I will do some testing but thanks for helping me figure it out this far

Comment: Sure happy to help.